# Is there a way to code a label and a switch in a ViewCell without using StackLayout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The application that I am working on has labels and on the right side a switch.  Here's a sample of the XAML that is used to achieve this:

```
<ViewCell x:Name="ss">
   <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20,0,20,0">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
         <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Text="Show Subcategory" YAlign="Center" XAlign="Center" />
         </StackLayout>
         <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Switch x:Name="ssSwitch" Toggled="SsSwitch" VerticalOptions="Center" />
         </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
   </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

What I would like to find out is if there is a more optimal way to achieve this.  The settings page has many switch settings and it seems like there are a large number of elements.

Does anyone have simpler way to achieve the same functionality or should I just stick with the many stacklayout elements?

Comment: you shouldn't really need the two innermost SL if they each contain only a single child element.  But in general you will need some sort of layout container whenever you want to have multiple elements contained in a single View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in SwitchCell but if you want/need to do a custom cell for your layout you can use a `Grid` instead of the `StackLayout`. It's more efficient and it's easier to define layouts.

```
<ViewCell x:Name="ss">
    <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:LabelBodyRendererClass  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Show Subcategory" YAlign="Center" XAlign="Center" />
        <Switch x:Name="ssSwitch" Grid.Column="1" Toggled="SsSwitch" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Using your example: you will have a 2-columns 1-row Grid. First column will be your custom control `LabelBodyRendererClass` and second column will be your switch.

Note that you can apply the Horizontal and Vertical option right in the UI Control.

More about [Grid](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/)

**Udpate**

Sure, you can use the `SwitchCell` from XAML just as you use any other cell.

```
<SwitchCell x:Name="SS" Text="{Binding Setting1Text}" On="{Binding Setting1}" />
<SwitchCell Text="{Binding Setting2Text}" On="{Binding Setting2}" />
<SwitchCell Text="{Binding Setting3Text}" On="{Binding Setting3}" />
<SwitchCell Text="{Binding Setting4Text}" On="{Binding Setting4}" />
```

These samples are using binding but as your CustomCell you can use the name to get and set the value from code behind, although I suggest you to use binding.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thanks,  As for the SwitchCell, is there a way to do that with XAML ?

Comment: Update the answer with samples using SwitchCell from XAML

Answer (score 0):

I guess is that what you are looking for: 
[image: SwitchCell]

Take a look [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.SwitchCell/).